# Can Fallback Strategy be used to reroll a natural 1 on an attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The spell [**Fallback Strategy**](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Fallback%20Strategy) has this condition:

> you may reroll one attack roll, combat maneuver check, or skill check
>   ***before the result*** of the roll or check ***is known***.

It seems at first glance that the "result" of rolling a natural 1 on a d20 for an attack roll is always known because a natural 1 is always a miss. My question is, does this mean that Fallback Strategy (and all spells with equivalent wording, like Lucky Number) cannot be used to reroll a natural 1 attack roll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK Paizo hasn't made errata for this. I believe the most common RAI is that even on a Natural 1, you can use abilities such as Fallback Strategy (there are a number of them now) unless you tell the GM, essentially. Not as in "oh don't look that didn't happen" but more of a "I'm not using that roll, I'm rerolling with x-ability".

**Essentially, you *knowing that your roll will have a bad result* and knowing the result are two different things.**

Results being revealed is a mechanic of the GM, not the player, therefore if you do not provide your natural one as your roll, you do not 'know the result', only what you expect the result to be.

This also fits with the intent of the abilities- getting a 2 is nearly as likely to fail almost any check just as assuredly as a 1, but you could use it on that.

[This Forum](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ptqn?Rerolls-and-how-you-handle-them) has a lot of speculation about the matter if you're interested.
[This reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/3vv0kz/an_interesting_rules_situation_is_the_die/) is about Misfortune but has a similar perspective about that reroll mechanic.